# Draw text in a window using Dev c++ without a project

Tags: c++

i want to draw a text in a window. when i use this file within a project, it runs fine without any error, when i run it alone, it shows below error. The requirement is to compile the file using only windows.h and in .cpp format.

```
[Linker error] undefined reference to `TextOutA@20' 
ld returned 1 exit status
```

i searched online, everyone says to add gdi32 lib. but that is only added to a project. i wonder if someone can help on this.

```
#include <windows.h>
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM) ;
int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,LPSTR szCmdLine, int    iCmdShow)
{
static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT ("My Window") ;
HWND hwnd ;
MSG msg ;
WNDCLASS wndclass ;
wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW ;
wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc ;
wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0 ;
wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0 ;
wndclass.hInstance = hInstance ;
wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION) ;
wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW) ;
//wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject (WHITE_BRUSH) ;
wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) COLOR_WINDOW+0;//DISPLAYS GREY BACKGROUND OF CLIENT   AREA
wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL ;
wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName ;
if (!RegisterClass (&wndclass))
{
MessageBox (NULL, TEXT ("Window not Registered"),
szAppName, MB_ICONERROR) ;
return 0 ;
}
hwnd = CreateWindow (szAppName, // window class name
TEXT ("abcd"), // window caption
WS_BORDER | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX, // window style
CW_USEDEFAULT, // initial x position
CW_USEDEFAULT, // initial y position
400,300,
NULL, // parent window handle
NULL, // window menu handle
hInstance, // program instance handle
NULL) ; // creation parameters
ShowWindow (hwnd, iCmdShow) ;
UpdateWindow (hwnd) ;
while (GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
TranslateMessage (&msg) ;
DispatchMessage (&msg) ;
}
return msg.wParam ;
}
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
HDC hdc ;
PAINTSTRUCT ps ;
RECT rect ;
HRGN bgRgn;
HBRUSH hBrush;
HPEN hPen;
switch (message)
{
case WM_PAINT:
hdc = BeginPaint (hwnd, &ps) ;
GetClientRect (hwnd, &rect) ;
TextOut(hdc, 50, 42, "Johnny Carson", 13);
EndPaint (hwnd, &ps) ;
return 0 ;
case WM_DESTROY:
PostQuitMessage (0) ;
return 0 ;
}
return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam) ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> i searched online, everyone says to add gdi32 lib. but that is only added to a project. i wonder if someone can help on this.

You need to link to gdi32.lib, that is where the code you are attempting to call resides.  It has nothing to do with a "project", which is a term used by IDE's and serves only as a model to manage your code.

You're asking your linker to link in code for a function call, yet you don't want to tell the linker where that code lives.  Well, the linker wins.

Comment: i added the line #pragma comment(lib, "gdi32.lib") at the top, telling  where the library file is but result is still the same

Comment: @MuhammadAsif: You need to pass the correct library path(s) to your linker and also tell it that gdi32.lib is a dependency. I don't know what else to say, this is extremely common and there's no getting around it. I have never used that #pragma so I didn't suggest it. Just configure your linker options properly like everyone else does.